# Multiple sql files in a directory which is in turn used in an unix script

Tags: sql, shell, unix, scripting, sqlplus

I have a script say **sql_result.sh** in directory **/tmp/SQL_QUERY** which just calls a sql script in the same location and executes the sql commands. 
Code:

```
sqlplus -S $MY_UN/$MY_PW@$MY_DB <<!
set serveroutput on;
@/tmp/SQL_QUERY/sql_file1
quit
!
```

However, if I have say 2 SQL files **sql_file1.sql** and **sql_file1.sql_new** in that directory. Which of the either sql scripts will my unix script pick? How and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: normally `sql_file1.sql`

The default extension is .SQL as explained in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1006685) for `@`:

```
file_name[.ext]

Represents the script you wish to run. If you omit ext, SQL*Plus assumes the default
command-file extension (normally SQL). For information on changing the default extension,
see the SUFFIX variable of the SET command.
```

As it says, you can use the `SET` command to change which extension is used, or you can specify the extension in the script explicitly.

The [SET](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1011230) command says:

```
Sets the default file extension that SQL*Plus uses in commands that refer to scripts. SUFFIX does not control extensions for spool files.

Example

To change the default command-file extension from the default, .SQL to .UFI, enter

SET SUFFIX UFI

If you then enter 

@EXAMPLE

SQL*Plus will look for a file named EXAMPLE.UFI instead of EXAMPLE.SQL.
```

*(Note that a `SET` command might be present in your LOGIN file.)*